# Docker Zulip: Not serving webpack bundle files with nginx proxy setup

Tags: docker, nginx, webpack, zulip

I tried installing this docker image on my ec2 instance machine with NGINX web server. But the static file is not displaying on my site. The webpack bundle files is being rendered using https://localhost.localdomain while other files is rendered the correct url https://zp.tastysites.dev

[image]

What seems to be lacking here? can you help?

here is the nginx config

```
server {


    server_name zp.tastysites.dev;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  https://127.0.0.1:5553;
    }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    certbots ssl here .....

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the [`EXTERNAL_HOST` setting](https://zulip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/production/settings.html#domain-and-email-settings) with the name at which users will visit your site.  In your case, that should be zp.tastysites.dev (even if Docker will internally forward it via localhost).